# How to execute nohup command with VLC in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, vlc

I cant seem to get this to work. If I execute the command like I always do then VLC closes.

here is the command

```
./vlc -vvv http://192.168.1.xx:6002 --sout '#transcode{venc=x264{preset=ultrafast},vcodec=h264,vb=1300,ab=128}:standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=192.168.1.50:9002}'
```

and here is the nohup command

```
nohup ./vlc -vvv http://192.168.1.xx:6002 --sout '#transcode{venc=x264{preset=ultrafast},vcodec=h264,vb=1300,ab=128}:standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=192.168.1.50:9002}' 2>&1 &;
```

This does not work. Am I doing something incorrectly?
Basically i want to execute the command and be to execute another commands as regular command produces continuous output

Comment: Could you provide details on how it doesnt work?

Answer (score 1):

There is a semicolon at the end of the second command, this will cause it to fail (as I found out earlier today). A semicolon is invalid following an `&` in bash, if you want another command on the the same line (usual reason for a semicolon), you just put a space after the `&` and add the other command.

That said `nohup` is not the way to stop vlc from producing 'continuous output'. For that you would do `&>/dev/null` instead of `2>&1`.

Comment: It gave me a pid but VLC doesnt seem to be doing the transcoding. If I execute the command without no hup it works:(

Comment: here is the output from the terminal
 nohup ./vlc -vvv http://192.168.1.50:9981/playlist/channelid/1 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=1900,ab=128}:standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=192.168.1.50:9002}' &>/dev/null &
[1] 3094
But no channel comes in

Comment: If you want to see if there is an error, you have to remove the `&>/dev/null` since this suppress output. Also, you realise the `-vvv` part makes vlc produce more output. Obviously it is redundant with `&>/dev/null`, but with a simple problem it is probably too much. Try without and if it doesn't tell you anything useful try `-v`, then `-vv` etc. `-vvv` is probably only really useful for developers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Tip: use cvlc

```
nohup ./cvlc -vvv 192.168.1.50:9981/playlist/channelid/1 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=1900,ab=128}:standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=192.168.1.50:9002}' &
```

This worked for me